# Accessing the parsed output buffer with the binary-parser Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, binary, decode

https://github.com/keichi/binary-parser

Does the binary-parser library for Node allow you to access the variables that have been parsed from your input buffer? The Quick-Start instructions state "***Parsed result will be returned as an object.***".

I can't see a mechanism to reference a constructor function, outlined in the Create API method.

***"create(constructorFunction)
Set the constructor function that should be called to create the object returned from the parse method."***

How can I access the data that was parsed? For the GitHub example, tcp.js, the values from the example tcp.js (shown below):

https://github.com/keichi/binary-parser/tree/master/example

```
var Parser = require('../lib/binary_parser').Parser;

var tcpHeader = new Parser()
    .endianess('big')
    .uint16('srcPort')
    .uint16('dstPort')
    .uint32('seq')
    .uint32('ack')
    .bit4('dataOffset')
    .bit6('reserved')
    .nest('flags', {
        type: new Parser()
            .bit1('urg')
            .bit1('ack')
            .bit1('psh')
            .bit1('rst')
            .bit1('syn')
            .bit1('fin')
    })
    .uint16('windowSize')
    .uint16('checksum')
    .uint16('urgentPointer');

var buf = new Buffer('e8a203e108e177e13d20756b801829d3004100000101080a2ea486ba793310bc', 'hex');

console.log(tcpHeader.parse(buf));
```

**binary-parser Output using *parse(buf)***

```
*{ srcPort: 59554,
  dstPort: 993,
  seq: 148994017,
  ack: 1025537387,
  flags: { urg: 0, ack: 1, psh: 1, rst: 0, syn: 0, fin: 0 },
  dataOffset: 8,
  reserved: 0,
  windowSize: 10707,
  checksum: 65,
  urgentPointer: 0 }*
```

What if I wanted to access the ***dstPort 993*** value - does binary-parser allow me to do this in Node.js?

In other words, how do I use the values from the parse operation? In my current limited knowledge of Node.js, I believe according to the documentation that I should be able to pick-off the values of the parse individually? Am I misinterpreting binary-parser's ability to assign variables name with types to variable that can be used in a user program? My goal is to access these variables whether in an array or other data structure in a later part of my program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your skill level is with JS, but you might try `var dstPort = tcpHeader.parse(buf).dstPort; console.log(dstPort)` and see if it says 993. That output looks like a JavaScript object--I don't know why you have asterisks around it. The parse function gives you a basic JavaScript Object the way you set it up, not anything particular to binary-parser.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that's gets me unstuck! MEAN stack day 3 on the skill level... I was under the impression (perhaps incorrectly) that the var definitions were done in the parser data structure, when in fact it only appears these are only labels(?) e.g. **.uint16('srcPort')** does not in fact execute **var dstPort =993;** behind the scenes. So do I need to create a var assignment now for every item in the buffer? e.g. var UrgentPointer=tcpHeader.parse(buf).UrgentPointer and so on?

Comment: Great! There are a lot of ways to make use of Objects, just check out the Object-related functions in the http://underscorejs.org toolkit.

Comment: Holy smoke! Thanks for the link - essential tooling!